# Rails self-join migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, self-join

I'm trying to use the Amoeba gem to create drafts by duplicating my Model. What I would like to do is create a self-join, such that:

`mainRecord.draft` gives the draft, and
`draftRecord.master` gives the master record.

The code should be simple enough:

```
class AddMasterToOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_reference :organizations, :master, foreign_key: { to_table: :organizations }
  end
end
```

With strong_migrations, however, it wants me to add the index concurrently, like so:

```
class AddMasterToOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    add_reference :organizations, :master, index: {algorithm: :concurrently}
  end
end
```

If I do that, I'm not sure what other migration to create to get the foreign key working properly.

Comment: What about using `add_reference :organizations, :master, index: {algorithm: :concurrently}, foreign_key: { to_table: :organizations }`?

Comment: Still doesn't like it:  `=== Dangerous operation detected #strong_migrations === Adding a foreign key blocks writes on both tables.... Add the foreign key in separate migrations.`

Comment: Can't you do that in a separate migration?

Comment: Yep, just wondering what the separate migration should look like. Not sure how foreign_key: { to_table: :organizations } translates to the 'add_foreign_key' form.